# Recycler View - one view opens up another

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with recycler view. I have several card views in it that can be expanded. After I click on one of them and scroll down, another one is opened aswell, but when I scroll back, the one that should be opened is closed. It's inconsistent and very confusing, I don't even know how to describe it. Thank you for your help.

**Recycler View item layout :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin_bottom"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin_sides"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin_sides"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_margin_top">

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/adapter_card_view_title_text_size"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expandText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/adapter_card_view_expand_text_size"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter :**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] headerText;
private String[] techniqueText;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView headerText;
    public TextView expandText;
    public CardView mCardView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
        super(v);
        mCardView = v;
        headerText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.headerText);
        expandText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandText);
    }
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] firstParam, String[] secondParam) {
    headerText = firstParam;
    techniqueText = secondParam;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((CardView) v,parent.getContext());
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.headerText.setText(headerText[position]);
    holder.expandText.setText(techniqueText[position]);
    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.expandText.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                holder.expandText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (holder.expandText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                holder.expandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return headerText.length;
}
```

}

**Recycler View setup** :

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)   v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_x);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(firstParam,secondParam);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: it is because recyclerview recycle cells.

Comment: Remember views are reused, so you need to reinitialize each view's state in the adapter's `getView`.

Answer (score 1):

Your views are being recycled. If you open a view and scroll down, that layout (in open state) will be recycled for a new entry, which will show open as well. You need to reset the state of each view when recycled, like so:

```
private final Set<Integer> mOpenIndices = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.headerText.setText(headerText[position]);
    holder.expandText.setText(techniqueText[position]);

    if (mOpenIndices.contains(position)) {
        holder.expandText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.expandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.expandText.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                holder.expandText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mOpenIndices.add(position);
            }
            else if (holder.expandText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                holder.expandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mOpenIndices.remove(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now you just need to keep track of view state (open/closed). You can use a Set of integers that contains the open view indices, for instance, or some other solution of your liking.

Comment: Where should I put that Set and what type it should be ? Im kinda confused

Answer (score 1):

The very concept of the RecyclerView is that it creates only a few views for the visible items, which are recycled when they go outside the screen limits. This makes a huge difference for big lists (think hundreds or thousands of items) in terms of memory and performance.

What happens to you is that a View is recycled and therefore loses its state. You need to explicitely store the state and restore it in `onBindViewHolder`. Something like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.headerText.setText(headerText[position]);
    holder.expandText.setText(techniqueText[position]);
    holder.expandText.setVisibility(expanded[position] ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            expanded[position] = !expanded[position]
            holder.expandText.setVisibility(expanded[position] ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

That means that you'll need an additional ArrayList called `expanded` with a size big enough to hold your state.

Comment: Where should I put that ArrayList and what type it should be ? Im kinda confused